# Simplify a vector cross product

Tags: vectors, determinant

I am trying to simplify down a vector cross product (**b**-**a**)x(**c**-**a**) using the properties of determinants. So far, I have spotted that the "binomial rule" could be employed possibly, but my working got real messy (I ended up with way too many determinants) which suggests I am not quite grasping the rule-please help!

Answer (score 0):

The cross product is distributive and anti-commutative, so your product can be expanded as $\bf a\times b + b\times c + c\times a$. Writing this out with the determinant for a 3-vector cross product does not appear to yield a particularly compact form when you collect the $\bf i,j$ and $\bf k$ elements, but I havent really explored this.

Comment: You should not have to use more than 3 determinants.

Comment: the fact that it has those properties and the result makes complete sense. It was a past paper question on a maths exam and worth 6 marks, so I went down the harder route!